# Find duplicates in a 3 Dimensional tuple list

Tags: python

At first, I apologize because I am a newbie...

I have one 3d list of tuple:

```
list=[(0, 1, 6), (5,1,4), (1, 6, 0), (3, 2,1),(4,5,1)]
```

I want to find duplicates and display like this, no matter the position of numbers ,only to have the same numbers :

```
{ (0,1,6): 2,
  (4,5,1): 2,
  (3,2,1): 1 }
```

I want to count the similar tuples.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are initializing your list with:

```
mylist = [[[(x,y,z) for x in range(7)] for y in range(7)] for z in range(7)]
```

At this point, you can change how you initialize it:

```
from collections import Counter

# take off some square brackets
mylist = [(x,y,z) for x in range(7) for y in range(7) for z in range(7)]

dict(Counter(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in mylist))
```

Output:

```
{(0, 0, 0): 1, (0, 0, 1): 3, (0, 0, 2): 3, (0, 0, 3): 3, (0, 0, 4): 3, (0, 0, 5): 3, (0, 0, 6): 3, (0, 1, 1): 3, (0, 1, 2): 6, (0, 1, 3): 6, (0, 1, 4): 6, (0, 1, 5): 6, (0, 1, 6): 6, (0, 2, 2): 3, (0, 2, 3): 6, (0, 2, 4): 6, (0, 2, 5): 6, (0, 2, 6): 6, (0, 3, 3): 3, (0, 3, 4): 6, (0, 3, 5): 6, (0, 3, 6): 6, (0, 4, 4): 3, (0, 4, 5): 6, (0, 4, 6): 6, (0, 5, 5): 3, (0, 5, 6): 6, (0, 6, 6): 3, (1, 1, 1): 1, (1, 1, 2): 3, (1, 1, 3): 3, (1, 1, 4): 3, (1, 1, 5): 3, (1, 1, 6): 3, (1, 2, 2): 3, (1, 2, 3): 6, (1, 2, 4): 6, (1, 2, 5): 6, (1, 2, 6): 6, (1, 3, 3): 3, (1, 3, 4): 6, (1, 3, 5): 6, (1, 3, 6): 6, (1, 4, 4): 3, (1, 4, 5): 6, (1, 4, 6): 6, (1, 5, 5): 3, (1, 5, 6): 6, (1, 6, 6): 3, (2, 2, 2): 1, (2, 2, 3): 3, (2, 2, 4): 3, (2, 2, 5): 3, (2, 2, 6): 3, (2, 3, 3): 3, (2, 3, 4): 6, (2, 3, 5): 6, (2, 3, 6): 6, (2, 4, 4): 3, (2, 4, 5): 6, (2, 4, 6): 6, (2, 5, 5): 3, (2, 5, 6): 6, (2, 6, 6): 3, (3, 3, 3): 1, (3, 3, 4): 3, (3, 3, 5): 3, (3, 3, 6): 3, (3, 4, 4): 3, (3, 4, 5): 6, (3, 4, 6): 6, (3, 5, 5): 3, (3, 5, 6): 6, (3, 6, 6): 3, (4, 4, 4): 1, (4, 4, 5): 3, (4, 4, 6): 3, (4, 5, 5): 3, (4, 5, 6): 6, (4, 6, 6): 3, (5, 5, 5): 1, (5, 5, 6): 3, (5, 6, 6): 3, (6, 6, 6): 1}
```

If you don't want to change how you initialized it:

```
def flatten(alist):
    for item in alist:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

dict(Counter(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in flatten(mylist)))
```

Comment: Here is with what I create my 3D List mylist = [[[(x,y,z) for x in range(7)] for y in range(7) ]for z in range(7)]

Comment: @Neo2 I made some modifications to my answer, it should work now.

Comment: @Neo2 I made another edit to my answer. If you don't want to change how you initialize your list, I gave another option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list=[(0, 1, 6), (5,1,4), (1, 6, 0), (3, 2,1),(4,5,1)]
>>> dict(Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)),list)))
{(0, 1, 6): 2, (1, 4, 5): 2, (1, 2, 3): 1}
>>>
```

Or a-style-of list comprehension:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list=[(0, 1, 6), (5,1,4), (1, 6, 0), (3, 2,1),(4,5,1)]
>>> dict(Counter([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in list]))
{(0, 1, 6): 2, (1, 4, 5): 2, (1, 2, 3): 1}
>>>
```

Also, `list` is a replica of a python keyword, after making that a variable, you would't have any access to the keyword anymore, so it's better to rename that variable, and so rename it in my code.

**Edit:**

Use:

```
dict(Counter([tuple(sorted(x)) for i in list for x in i]))
```

Comment: Here is with what I create my 3D List                                                                     
  li = [[[(x,y,z) for x in range(7)] for y in range(7) ]for z in range(7)]

Comment: @naivepredictor Actually, what i mean by explanation is some text at least mentioning how ya do it, the type or function.

Comment: My code for the creation of the list is:mylist= [[[(x,y,z) for x in range(1,7)] for y in range(1,7) ]for z in range(1,7)]

Comment: Because it is a 3dimensional I get the errors?I dont know

Comment: @Neo2 Now? does my code work, also please accept if it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make a dataframe out of the list
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ll)

# sort columns and find duplicates
df_dup = df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
               .duplicated(keep=False)]

# return duplicates as dictionary of tuples
result = df_dup.T.apply(tuple).to_dict()

# return number of duplicates found
n = len(result)
```

Comment: you have got something wrong with your keyboard as first two characters are in capital and you have multiple explanation marks. Probably some food got stuck between the keys of your keyboard and key with number 1 got pressed and stuck. better check it mate.

Comment: See bottom of my post. also, should post it as regular text, not in the code.

Comment: Actually, you're saying my keyboard, that's actually what i wanted to do :-)

Comment: U9-Forward why do you remove your comments? First you write something like this "NO!!!! don't do that ...' hence why I suggested you have problem with your keyboard then you remove your comment so my comment is obsolete. shall I remove mine as well?

Comment: That's how i wanted it.

Comment: if this is how you wanted then stop shouting at people from behind of the screen of your monitor

Comment: Sorry,  i was just little upset :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[(0, 1, 6), (5,1,4), (1, 6, 0), (3, 2,1),(4,5,1)]

#first please make a list of sorted tuples to ignore the sequence of numbers
sorted_list = [sorted(x) for x in list]

#then count the tuple in sorted list and ignore count for duplicated items.
list = [ { x: sorted_list.count(sorted(x)) } for i, x in enumerate(list) if sorted(x) not in sorted_list[:i]]

print(list);
```

Comment: I tried to explain by putting comments.. so if you have still any confusion, please ask. I will try to explain.

Comment: Please don't do that, click the [edit] button under the post, then edit as you want.

Comment: But I want to count the dublicates

Comment: Neo2: Please once check the result of my code.. It will give result as you want :). I mean by that comment... Ignoring to count again for tuple which has been counted already.

Answer (score 0):

as suggestion, not to use keyword in python as a variable, here is the keywords in python:

```
import keyword
keyword_list = keyword.kwlist
```

for your question, here is my answer :

```
from collections import Counter

result = dict(Counter([tuple(sorted(item)) for item in your_list ]))
```